# Are the Old Slavonic interrogative particle "еда" and verb "быти" to be related in any way?

Tags: etymology

Are the Old Slavonic interrogative particle "еда (ʲeda)" and verb "быти (byti)" to be related in any way?

For example, on the basis of:

1. existence the following present forms of the verb:

есмь (ʲesm'), еси (ʲesi), есть (ʲest')

2. existence the Old Slavonic alternating consonants rule д->с (d->s):

я**д**ь -> я**с**ти;
во**д**ити ве**с**ти;
бро**д**ити бре**с**ти

3. constructing an interrogative sentence by analogy with european languages (putting on an auxiliary verb at the beginning of a sentences):

**Hath** the LORD indeed **spoken** only by Moses?
**Est**-ce seulement par Moïse que l'Éternel **parle**?
**Еда** ли моисию единому **глагола** господь?

4. existence the conjugation parrallel with the verb "ясти"

Noun ядь; verb ясти
Conjugation:
я ямъ ты я**си** мы ямы вы я**сте** он я**сть**

Noun еда? (in the Old Slavonic, second meaning); verb быти
Conjugation:
я есмь ты е**си** мы есмы вы е**сте** он е**сть**

Comment: It seems obvious, yes, but compare *da* "yes". The homophone *jeda* "to eat, meal" and *jesti* "to eat; am, have" is curious. Affarmitive *jesti* has been compared as loanword of En. *yes*? The Proto Indo European roots for these senses are reconstructed differently: \*h1es- (whence *was, is*, etc.) and \*bhew- (*to be*) versus \*h1ed- (*to eat*, Ger. *Essen*, etc). I'm not sure that's certain and straight forward. Perhaps compare Ger. question particle  *bitte?* "please", presentive *bitte, da* "voila, there you go", PIE \*gʷʰedʰ- "ask, pray"; En. *bid* PIE \*bʰewdʰ-; Rom. *da* "give" *deh3

Comment: also *dʰeh₁- (“to put”) - *to do* and the like.

Comment: En. *justice*, *judicial* show the same correspondance, so I'm sure that's not limited to slavonic.

Comment: Affirmative jesti? 
Есть (ʲesť) is:
The Russian form of the Old Slavonic verb ясти (jasti);
The Russian present form of the verb "быти" ("to be") for all pronouns;
The Old Slavonic present form of the verb "быти" ("to be") for third-person singular.
Еда ʲeda is:
the Russian noun (En. meal)
Old Slavonic interrogative particle 
You may have a look at https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%B5/%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0
You may disregard all that concerns Russian forms!
I'll rewrite my post basing on Old Slavonic words only (exclude russian terms).
Your latest comment is brilliant.

Comment: The Old Slavonic present form ʲesť (En. is) of the verb "быти" ("to be") for third-person singular has been compared to the Old Slavonic interrogative particle ʲeda.

Comment: Your analogies are very doubtful. Dentals /t/ and /d/ get affricated in various contexts in various languages: the reverse change is rare. There is no part of either verb (the root of 'esti' or of 'byti') which is reconstructed with a /d/ as far as I know.

Comment: @ColinFine But there are many other Old Slavonic verbs, that have a part /s/, which is reconstructed with a /d/. e.g. you may have a look at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30560/are-the-old-slavonic-noun-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-and-verb-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8-to-be-related-in-any-way

The meaning of the Old Slavonic interrogative particle ʲeda is если(ʲesli; En. if), which previously had the form естьли (ʲesťl')

Comment: Book of Micah 3:11 
"Is not the LORD among us? none evil can come upon us."

 "Еда ли господь в насъ, не приидетъ зло на ны"

Comment: The Ancient Greek also had alternating consonants "feature" d<->s:
+ An. Gr. παῖς (país) παιδίον (paidíon)

Comment: @prostorech: yes, there are. But esti isn't one of them. Whether you look at 'is', 'ist', 'est', 'asti', 'jesti', 'eshte' , 'asmi', 'am',  'sum', or any other reflex in IE, there is no /d/.

Comment: I might add to my *da* tangetn that a spurious *e-* is added to other words, particles like in э́такой, этот. Given that your spelling of быти is nonstandard, as far as I can tell from a quick search without any knowledge of Russian, I'd assume that you mean \*эда /eda/, could that be?

Comment: @ColinFine au contraire, AGr ἦτον (êton) 2., 3. p. dual pres. acv. subj. of εἰμί (eimí).

Comment: этот, эта, это, эдакий, эдакая, эдакое are the russian words while еда is old slavonic word with different meaning. The Old Slavonic equivalents of words этот, эта, это are сей, сия, сие

Comment: -e- occures in the other Old Slavonic words, e.g.егда, елико, ельмаже

Comment: @vectory: and where, precisely, is /d/ in  ἦτον ?

Comment: @ColinFine The Verb 'byti' contains the etymological root /d/, that elides before the "ti" ending by analogy with the Old Slavonic verb дать (dati)[En. to give].

The etymological root /d/ comes up at the time of future tense conjugation:

Я буду (ʲa budu) [En. I will]

Comment: @ColinFine The etymological root /d/ transforms into an /s/ during the aorist tense conjugation, e.g. бысть (byst')

Comment: @prostorech: 1) what evidence have you that the /d/ of "budu" is part of the root? Since I know of no reflexes in non-Slavonic languages with a /d/, I doubt this. 2) Analogy can be a useful explanation for unexpected forms. Using it to posit forms which are unrecorded and inconsistent with their cognates is a futile exercise. 3) Even if you succeed in establishing a historical /d/ in the root of 'byti', this will do precisely nothing to establish a /d/ in the root of 'jesti'.

Comment: @ColinFine 1) One-vowel-root Old Slavonic words during the aorist tense conjugation have two equivalent forms for third-person singular: бы/бысть; (Inf. быти [byti] En. to be); пи/питъ (Inf. пити[piti] En. to drink); жи/житъ (Inf. жити [gyti] En. to live); начя/начятъ ("на" is the prefix; Inf. начяти [nach'ati] En. to begin ); яде/ясть (Inf. ясти ['asti] En. to eat); даде/дасть (Inf. дати [dati] En. to give); Words that truly don't have root /d/ get the extra part /тЪ/ only while "other" words get the transformed root /s/ and the extra part /тЬ/

Comment: Please pay attention, that letter /Ъ/ and /Ь/ are not same. In other words, if the verb /byti/ really does not have the root /d/ it's third-person singular aorist form should looks like the "bytъ" in /byst'/ stead.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89903/discussion-on-question-by-prostorech-are-the-old-slavonic-interrogative-particle).

Comment: @ColinFine You may have a look at Deutsch verb /wissen/ "En. to know" and then take a look at Old Slavonic verb /вѣдѣти/ (v'ed'eti) "En. to know", which have the same PIE origin.

Is this an example of reflexe in non-Slavonic languages with a /d/?

Comment: @ColinFine The alternating consonants rule usage u->y (budu/byti) you may see on the following examples:

/студ / stud/ En. shame -> /стыдение / stydeniye/ En. nakedness

/воздух / vozdukh/ En. air -> /воздыхание / vozdykhaniye/ En. sighing 

/слух / slukh/ En. fame -> /слышание / slyshaniye/ En. audience

Comment: @prostorech: this conversation has been moved to chat. Do not continue it here.

Answer (score 2):

I will translate my [Russian answer](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/448547/178412) as there is a chance that here it is more likely to be discussed.

**No, these words are not related.**

To begin with, if some forms are included in the same paradigm it does not really mean that they share one root. *Быть* has a present form *есть* and this form is ***suppletive*** (it is not cognate).

Under these reasons, *быть* and *еда* 'particle' are not related. But the next question is if *есть* 'pres. of *быть*' and еда 'particle' are cognate. And the answer is **no**. In ***ед**а* we probably see the same **ed-* as in ***ед**иный* 'single' which is of IE origin (compare Latin *ecce* < *ed+ce 'yes, look!', NHG *etwas* 'something, *etlich* 'some').

<sub>Ref. Этимологический словарь русского языка (ЭСРЯ), V. 1, Issue 6, p. 246.</sub>

Comment: Do you consider "ʲe" to be a part of historical root of the following words:

егда (когда,тогда, иногда, оногда, овогда), елико (колико, толико), еже (яже,юже,иже), коеждо (каяждо,кыиждо)?